# Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be isometries. Show that the conjugacy $\psi\circ\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is of the same type as $\varphi$

Tags: geometry

Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be isometries. Show that the conjugacy $\psi\circ\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is of the same type of $\varphi$ (i.e. if $\varphi$ a translation, then so is $\psi\circ\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$, if $\varphi$ is a rotation, then so is $\psi\circ\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$...)

The only thing I proved is that the dimension of the space of the fixed point is the same, but is it enough? If not, how can I do it ?

Comment: Not enough. Need to show these "conjugates" are translations, rotations, which is more than just dimension of fixed point spaces same.

Comment: @coffeemath: So how can I do it ?

Comment: It's not true for general functions $\psi$; for example, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric, if $\varphi(x) = x+1$ and $\psi(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ then $(\psi \circ \varphi \circ \psi^{-1})(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^3 + 1}$, which is not an isometry.

Comment: @ConnorHarris: Sorry, $\psi$ is an isometrie also.

Comment: make explicit usage of definitions of rotation reflection translation etc

Answer (score 0):

First, break the proof into cases, using the classification of isometries.

Then analyze each case separately.

**Rotations:** If $\phi$ is a rotation of angle $\theta$ around a fixed point, then you must prove that $\psi \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also a rotation of angle $\theta$ around a fixed point. [NOTE: Rotations are characterized by having a 0-dimensional fixed point set. But the rotation angle is also part of the classification of isometries, and so you need to also prove that the rotation angle is invariant.]

**Reflections:** If $\phi$ is a reflection, then you must prove that $\psi \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also a reflections. [NOTE: reflections are characterized as having a 1-dimensional fixed point set. In this case, knowing that the fixed point set has dimension 1 is necessary and sufficient to conclude that the isometry is a reflection, and there's no other invariant]

**Translations:** If $\phi$ is a translation which moves each point a distance equal to $d$, then you must prove that $\psi \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also a translation which moves each point a distance equal to $d$.

**Glide reflection:** If $\phi$ is a glide reflection, moving points along its axis by a distance $d$, you must prove that $\psi \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also a glide reflection, moving points along its axis by a distance $d$.

[NOTE: Translations and glide reflections each have empty fixed point set. So clearly you need to do more to distinguish between them. But as with rotation, the translation distance $d$ is part of the classification of translations and of glide reflections, and so you need to also prove that the translation distance $d$ is invariant]

Don't forget the easy one:

**The identity:** If $\phi$ is the identity then you must prove that $\psi \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is the identity.

Comment: In what that help ? You are exactly repeating my exercise....

Comment: No, I did not exactly repeat your exercise. I pointed out *additional invariants* that will make the exercise easier if you incorporate them into your work. For exmaple, you wrote "if $\phi$ is a rotation then so is $\psi\phi\psi^{-1}$", whereas I wrote "if $\phi$ is a rotation of angle $\theta$ around a fixed point, then $\psi\phi\psi^{-1}$ is a rotation of angle $\theta$ around a fixed point". So, if you incorporate the rotation angle into your work, then you will find the proof easier. However, if you find this unhelpful, I will delete this answer.